# Listview within TabHost using SQLite Database List Population Issue

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-tabhost

I am using Tabhost and inside each tab I am using the same listview activity with an SQLite database to populate the list.

My question is how would I get the list to show different items for each tab? I have tried passing the tabId through the intent to the main activity however it acts with a 1 click delay on the tabs. For example if I click tab 1-2-3-2, then the getIntent() method thinks it is 1-1-2-3. I have even tried making a method in the database to pass the id through.

Comment: can you provide more details or even a picture of the idea you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: Have you tried it using Viewpager, TabBarLayout and FragmentAdapter for viewpager and SQLite database accessed with content provider and cursor loader I think that will be the better solution for your requirement.